# Alternatives to background-attachment: fixed

Tags: html, css, background-attachment

Since background-attachment:fixed doesn't work on some mobile browsers (e.g. on iOS), what alternatives are there, specifically when trying to implement the following demo: http://cppforums.ludost.net/test/test.html

CSS:

```
.sec1 { 
  min-height: 1000px;
  background: #222 url('wallpaper-2959361.jpg') no-repeat center top fixed;
}

.sec2 { 
  min-height: 1000px;
  background: #222 url('wallpaper-1829278.jpg') no-repeat center top fixed;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="sec1">text</div>
<h1>Title 1</h1>
<div class="sec2">more text</div>
<h1>Title 2</h1>
<div class="sec1">even more text</div>
```

Any suggestions on how to implement the demo in a way that works on all browsers? Preferably a CSS only solution.

Comment: Three things to think about. 1. File size and loadtime on a mobile device. 2. With or without it does it take from the general construct of your website. 3. Mobile websites do not have to follow the same construct as a normal website. Mobile should mean that the website is functional on a phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    .bg 
    {
      background-image: url(bg.jpg);
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      z-index: -1;
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
      pointer-events: none;
    }
```

See this example: https://rawgit.com/arnaudbreton/background-fixed-chrome-rendering-issue/master/index-without-rendering-issue.html

Taken from:
http://blog.mention.com/building-a-beautiful-homepage-how-we-nailed-down-chrome-performance-rendering-issues/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery alternative to `background-attachment:fixed;` (be sure to have jQuery properly installed):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
     var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();
     $('.sec1').css('background-position', 'center ' + ((scrolledY)) + 'px');
});
```

It is important to note that your background image must not be taller than the height of the div or things get thrown off.